# ArcGIS Runtime: Get elevation data fast

Tags: c#, .net, arcgis, esri

I'm developing with ArcGIS Runtime SDK for dotNet 10.2.6.

I need to get elevation data of points from a local DTM file (in TIF format) several dozen times in a second.

I'm using the elevation data to calculate the intersection point of a viewer's line-of-sight with the ground.
(e.g. - my camera is at some point, looking at some azimuth with some pitch, I need to calculate the point on the ground which it's looking at)

I tried to use an IdentifyTask for getting the elevation data in points along the line-of-sight, but this is slow (20-40 milliseconds per query, a few seconds in total).

My IdentifyTask:

```
IdentifyParameters identifyParams = new IdentifyParameters(mapPoint, m_MapView.Extent, 1, (int)m_MapView.ActualHeight, (int)m_MapView.ActualWidth);
identifyParams.DynamicLayerInfos = m_DynamicMapServiceLayer.DynamicLayerInfos;
identifyParams.ReturnGeometry = false;
identifyParams.SpatialReference = m_MapView.SpatialReference;
identifyParams.LayerOption = LayerOption.Top;

IdentifyResult identifyResult = await identifyTask.ExecuteAsync(identifyParams);
```

Note:
I tried using a Geoprocessor task to calculate the LOS - this was not much faster.

Is there any faster way to get elevation data from a point (or a line) using a local raster DTM file?

Comment: Have you thought about actually running multiple requests in parallel? I get the impression that you're using `await` to get the result of each request before sending off the next one (hence '20-40ms per query, a few seconds in total'), whereas you should be able to fire off multiple requests at once and look at the result as they come back. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx

Comment: I tried to measure 200 points with - await Task.WhenAll(tasks), it took about 6 seconds (~30ms per task).

Answer (score 0):

You could try SceneView and FileElevationSource. Then use FileElevationSource.GetElevationAsync(). Using an STRM .tif file I see around 6 ms / sample:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SceneView sv = new SceneView();
        FileElevationSource elv = new FileElevationSource();
        elv.Filenames.Add(@"C:\Maps\NJ\elev\n40_w075_1arc_v3.tif");
        sv.Scene.ElevationSourceLoaded += (object sender, ElevationSourceLoadedEventArgs e) =>
        {
            elevtest(elv);
        };
        sv.Scene.Surface.Add(elv);
        Content = sv;
        sv.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    async void elevtest(FileElevationSource elv)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        double nSamples = 1000.0;
        double delta = 1 / nSamples;
        for (double i = 0; i < 1.0; i += delta)
        {
            double elev = await elv.GetElevationAsync(new Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Geometry.MapPoint(-75 + i, 40 + i, SpatialReferences.Wgs84));
        }
        sw.Stop();
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / nSamples + " ms per sample" );
    }
```

If it still not good enough you can use [GDAL](http://gdal.org/) to read and access the elevation data. That will be much faster.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The SceneView result is indeed faster, but for some reason I get different results from the IdentifyTask for the same point... (at some points the difference is more than 50). Also, how can I tell the units of the result? And is there a way to use a query to get the elevation of multiple point with one result?